# Discharge waste water - content allowed, most strict, universal rule set

Tags: water, environmental-protection

Where can I find non-country specific, general or most strict set of rules that would pass in most countries, about allowed content of waste water that is allowed to be released into the environment, in most cases?

Excluding special cases like ships or particular factories or some countries that are particularly forgiving, or nature reserve rules that are particularly strict.

For example, about compounds with C, Fe, Zn, Al, Na, Ca, S, Cl, P, Si, O, H as ions or particles (per particle size), pH

Preferably not in a form of 800 pages book that just lists what is prohibited in each specific case.

Comment: The municipal water supply  ,and certainly well water, will contain many of those elements as it enters the distribution system.